# Perl's grep does not work with dereferenced array

Tags: arrays, perl, grep, dereference

I wanted to find a perl equivalent to a python `var in list` idiom and stumbled on this.

The perl grep can do a `grep { $_ eq $var } @list` expression to match the element in list logic.

If I use a derefenced array like `grep { $_ eq $var } @$list` with $list defined as ['foo', 'bar'], I don't get the same outcome.

Is there a way to make grep work using dereferenced arrays?

Comment: Can you be more specific? Please post an [mcve]. `my $var = 'foo'; say for grep { $_ eq $var } @{ [qw/foo bar/] }` works like a charm on 5.20.1 for me.

Comment: `List::Util::any` may be better that `grep` in this case because it stops after first match.

Comment: [`Data::Munge::elem`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Munge#elem-SCALAR,-ARRAYREF) can also do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That idiom should work fine; I think a code example where it's not working would be helpful.  Just as a quickie toy example of this, though:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use Test::More;

sub find_var {
    my ($var,$array) = @_;
    print "Testing for $var in [" . join(',',@$array) . "]...\n";
    if ( grep $var eq $_, @$array ) {
        return "found it";
    } else {
        return "no match!\n";
    }
}

my @array = qw(apple pear cherry football);
my $var = 'football';
my $var2 = 'tomato';

is(find_var($var, \@array), 'found it');
is(find_var($var2, \@array), 'found it');
done_testing();
```

This results in the following output, which indicates that the first test for "football" in the array reference was successful, while the second test for "tomato" was not:

```
Testing for football in [apple,pear,cherry,football]...
ok 1
Testing for tomato in [apple,pear,cherry,football]...
not ok 2
#   Failed test at array.pl line 22.
#          got: 'no match!
# '
#     expected: 'found it'
1..2
# Looks like you failed 1 test of 2.
```

Comment: Just realized my error which was a simple typo, yes this idiom should work for dereferenced arrays